# reflection, получить ссылку на поле структуры

Tags: golang, рефлексия

Добрый день,

Изучаю Go, пытаюсь разобраться с reflection

Есть пример:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type AppConfig struct {
    Pg string `cli:"pg" env:"PG" default:"host=host.local dbname=db user=user password=password" description:"Connection to PostgreSQL"`
}

func main() {
    config := &AppConfig{}
    GetConfig(config)
    fmt.Println(config.Pg)
}
func GetConfig(config interface{}) interface{} {
    e := reflect.ValueOf(config).Elem()
    t := e.Type()
    flag.StringVar(
        e.Field(0).Interface().(*string),
        t.Field(0).Tag.Get("cli"),
        t.Field(0).Tag.Get("default"),
        t.Field(0).Tag.Get("description"))
    flag.Parse()
    return config
}
```

Ссылка на playground https://play.golang.org/p/KmQDYJaizl

При запуске ожидаемо получаю:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not *string
```

Если заменить `e.Field(0).Interface().(*string)` на боее коректное (с моей точки зрения) `&e.Field(0).Interface().(string)` получаю:

```
main.go:22: cannot take the address of e.Field(0).Interface().(string)
```

Собственно вопрос - что не правильно понимаю?
Или что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужен адрес, то и берите [`Addr`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Addr). Замените

```
e.Field(0).Interface().(*string),
```

на

```
e.Field(0).Addr().Interface().(*string),
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/3APNXAtooK.

Comment: Спасибо, пытался через .Pointer(), а вот .Addr() не рассматривал